# Compute the difference between two sets (sorted and simple)

Tags: redis

Is there a way to compute the difference between two **sorted sets** (zset) or do I have to use simple sets for this?

Problem:

1. Set **F** contains a list of sorted id's (sorted set, full list)
2. Set **K** contains a list of id's (simple set, subset of F)

I want to retrieve every entry in **F**, in order, that's not in **K**.

Is this possible using Redis alone or do I have to do the computation on the application? If yes, what is the best way?

EDIT: [SDIFF](http://redis.io/commands/sdiff) does not suit this purpose as it doesn't allow sorted sets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make a copy of F as a simple set.  Let's call it G.  Now perform the SDIFF.

Or...

Make a copy of F as a sorted set.  Let's call it G.  Iterate through K and remove each element from G.

SDIFF really should work on sorted sets, regular sets, or combinations.  But, at this time, it does not.

Also, if F is very large, you may see some performance hits when you make a copy of it.  In this case, create a set G in your Redis DB that it updated when K is updated.  That is, F and G are initially equal.  As you add elements to K, remove the element from G.